# Visual Studio 2022 Update 17.9.5 Removes Collaborator Repositories Visibility in GitHub

Tags: visual-studio, github

I was using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit), specifically Version 17.7.0, and it has recently been updated to Version 17.9.5. However, after the update, the Collaborator Repositories are no longer visible in GitHub, only Your Repositories are displayed.

I've noticed this issue on two other PCs after updating them as well. When I restore the previous version, Collaborator Repositories are once again visible alongside Your Repositories.